# How to use .dot extension files(graphviz readable) to make graphs with Oligrapher?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, graphviz, dot

I want to use oligrapher to make interactive and beautiful graphs but I have .dot file format data, how do I use .dot file format, which results in a graph using graphviz, to make graphs using Oligrapher?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Google search does not find any existing conversion tools
- the Oligrapher schema: https://github.com/public-accountability/oligrapher#data-schema
- use **dot**, **neato**, or **fdp** **-Tdot** or **-Tjson** to create a starting point for the map (see: https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/)
- convert to Oligrapher data format manually or programmatically

Comment: Seems like I'll have to use regex to convert to Oligrapher data format programmatically, is there any other approach to be able to do it programmatically?